# How could I print  a webpage that it's not loaded?

Tags: javascript, printing, html

I'm in a webpage and I would like that when I click on a "print" link, open the "print box" and be able to print other page. I have the href of the webpage that I want to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your print button open a new window with the other page as the URL, and have that page fire window.print() in the onload handler. That or using CSS media queries like @darin suggested is the only way.

Comment: It's works ! I have an window.open() and onLoad="window.print();" on the popup's body. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. It's the user that decides what he wants to print in his browser, not you. So simply provide a link to this other site in your page and invite the user to navigate to it and print it. You could also apply a [print CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) for the current page if you want to change the style.

Comment: In fact, I would like to print not the current view but an other page... I have ever see that in websites...